# Bad sound on headphones if I don't press mic button

Tags: sound, headphones

I've just bought these headphones: [www.amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009HQTORS)

They have a mic button so you can talk when attached to a mobile.

If I use the headphones in a mobile (I've just tested Samsung S3 and S1) it works like a charm.

But if I use them with my Sony Laptop with Ubuntu, sound quality is really bad. If the player is flash, sound is not good. If it is not, sound is just horrible. But if I press mic button, sound is perfect!!

What can I do?

Comment: Try this: Insert the jack completely and then pull it out just a little bit(hardly 1mm). It might work for you.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really off-topic. The problem is *caused* by hardware, but some solutions are nonetheless possible [in software](https://askubuntu.com/a/319264/22949). (The problem was also described as having been affected by what program was used...)

Answer (score 18):

It is very simple. The headphones with mic aren't compatible with the only headphone jack.

The headphones with mic used with phone has 4 step. The standard configuration is either CTIA or OMTP. The tip is audio L, next step is audio right, 3rd step is ground (or may be mic) and 4th step is mic (or ground).

On the other hand the headphone jack only compatible with 3 pin, audio L, audio R and ground.

The reason you get horrible sound because of those last two steps. When you press the mic button, it shorts the ground with mic which intern makes your headset act like earphone without mic.

This is not related anything to ubuntu. Pure hardware issue. You need to get a 4pin to 3 pin spliter like below, or if you're having this similar problem on a mobile try the second picture

[image][2](http://www.mophie.com/shop/media/resized/484x173_wysiwyg-audio-extender-3qtr.jpg)

Comment: Another simple solution which works for me is to not push the plug all the way in. Slowly push it inwards and find the place where both the left and the right channels are receiving audio.

Comment: Or get a rubber band and put it on the remote to keep the button pressed. EDIT: Someone suggested a binder clip at the bottom of the page

Comment: Does this phenomenon have a name? Do you have a link where I can read more about it?

Comment: @whoKnows a starting point http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-8-how-guides/249287-note-headset-standards-omtp-ahj-apple.html

Comment: @Sicco's workaround is ideal for use with desktops, but presumably less so for laptops and mobile devices. In my case, my Xiaomi Pistons 2 (*...Chi-fi IEM for the win!*) behave as expected when connected directly but *not* when connected indirectly through a headphone extension cable. In the latter case, leaving the extension cable *slightly* unplugged from the input audio port of my desktop sufficed to resolve this. In short, **this issue is totally absurd.** (A lack of coherent standards across the hi-fi industry is why we can't have good things.) `</sigh>`

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest going to Sound Settings and try adjusting them. The bad sound might be an issue that can be fixed through the laptops' settings... If you have tried this, please let me know for further details.

Regards, 
Anthie G.

[image]

Comment: I cannot resolve the issue using Sound Settings (or I don't know how to do it)

Comment: Plug your headphones in and go to sound settings. Go to the "Output" tab click on your headphones and try adjusting the settings.

* See the picture above :) (I edited my answer) :)

Comment: For anyone reading this: this is the answer, turn your balance all the way left or right and it will fix it

Answer (score 2):

For the laptop, I just put a small binder clip over the microphone button, keeping it permanently pressed. Problem is most new ear bud come with the microphone, so you may have to shop around.