# Why is my mobile's headset not detected properly on my laptop's combined mic/headphone input?

Tags: 14.04, sound, audio-jack, detect

I'm using an HP EliteBook 9470m. It has one single combined input jack for microphone and headphone. I get clear nice sound with headphones missing a microphone, i.e headphones with only a three contact jack as shown on the right in the picture below.

When I use my phones headset (four contact connector on the left in the picture below), I get somewhat weak sound. I have to keep pressing the headset's button to get full sound quality.

[image: Audio jacks]

I assume Ubuntu does not auto-detect the kind of jack that is plugged in. How do I get Ubuntu to recognize my mobile's headset?

Comment: My question is similar to [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/319253/17789), except that my laptop has a combined audio jack that should in principle work.

Comment: May be it's a  hardware compatibility issue. Try a headset from another manufacture. Also try to insert it partially (90%)

Comment: The 90% work. I noticed it before. But it's not a solution. The jack just pops out this way, if I don't hold it in place.

Comment: Does it means that [this dialog](http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/files/2014/03/What-did-you-plug-in.png) which allows you to select your headphone type won't pop-up when you plug it in?

Comment: I've never seen it to this day.

Answer (score 0):

This clearly have to do with pulseaudio package indeed.

Perhaps this helps:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure